# A better way of building a new string after swapping its contents

Tags: java, string, thread-safety, char, stringbuilder

I am manipulating ssn.
  Input ="123456789"
  Output="896745123"

You take the first 3 digits from the input (i.e 123) and swap it with the last two digits "89" and then swap "45" with "67". Below is the code I have using toCharArray. But I didn't like it. This method (not the test) can be accessed by many users at a time. I was looking for a better in performance, readability and trade safe solution.

I appreciate your help.

```
@Test
    public void testSSNString(){

        String original="123456789";
        String result="896745123";
        char[] charResult=original.toCharArray();

        char temp=charResult[6];
        charResult[6]=charResult[0];
        charResult[0]=charResult[7];
        charResult[7]=charResult[1];
        charResult[1]=charResult[8];
        charResult[8]=charResult[2];
        charResult[2]=charResult[5];
        charResult[5]=charResult[4];
        charResult[4]=charResult[3];
        charResult[3]=temp;

        assertEquals(original.toCharArray(),charResult);

    }
```

Comment: Tthis is perfectly thread-safe and utmostly performant. No solution can beat the hardcoded mapping you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you have given is essentially the best you can do in Java in terms of performance. Using arrays is faster than using `StringBuilder`.

To improve readability, I would just make some small changes, like making a new array for the permuted output:

```
@Test
public void testSSNString() {
  String original = "123456789";
  String expected = "896745123";

  char[] in = original.toCharArray();
  char[] out = new char[9];
  out[0] = in[7];
  out[1] = in[8];
  out[2] = in[5];
  out[3] = in[6];
  out[4] = in[3];
  out[5] = in[4];
  out[6] = in[0];
  out[7] = in[1];
  out[8] = in[2];

  assertEquals(expected.toCharArray(), out);
}
```

Comment: There COULD be a marginal performance improvement (and also a reduction in code) if you used several calls to `System.arrayCopy`.

Comment: Sweet (and this is for "enter at least 15 characters")

Comment: One thing I want to add. I created a method and put this logic in that method and return "out.toString()" however. out.toString is returning the address not the string representation of "out" . Why is that? Though return new String(out); works fine.

Comment: For `char[] -> String` conversion, use [`new String(out)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char[]%29).

Comment: @NayukiMinase. That's what I did. But I am wondering why char[]-> String is not giving me the string not the address?

Comment: If you did something like `char[] c={...}; print("" + c)`, then it will print the hashcode of `c` because `c` is an array. This will happen to any array type. `char` arrays are not special.

Comment: @NayukiMinase True that. But when I try c.toString(), I was expecting it to return the String of that char array. Am I wrong?

Comment: Oh, it's because for `"" + c` translates to `"" + c.toString()`. Does this answer your question?